# Linear Algebra, multiplication of Tensor by vector by vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, optimal-control

I am deriving some equations and need to know the correct mathematical notation for opening up the brackets of an equation with the following variables:
tensor $A \in$ ${\mathbb R}^{l \times l \times l}$, a vector $\mathbf{x} \in {\mathbb R}^{l \times 1}$ and a vector $\mathbf{y} \in {\mathbb R}^{l \times 1}$.

I need to open up the following brackets, specifically interested in multiplying out the $A\mathbf{x}$ term: 
$(something + A\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{x})$.

What is correct? 
For first term
$\mathbf{y}^TA\mathbf{x}$ or
$\mathbf{x}^TA^T\mathbf{y}$ or
$(A\mathbf{x})\mathbf{y}$ or
$A\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}$?

Equally for the second term:
$\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}$ or
$\mathbf{x}^TA^T\mathbf{x}$ or
$(A\mathbf{x})\mathbf{x}$ or
$A\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}$?

### My actual derivations are below:

A commonly studied nonlinear system describing the evolution of the state takes the form
\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)) = \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t))\mathbf{x}(t) + \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t))\mathbf{u}(t)
\end{equation}
where $\widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^{{l}\times{l}}$ and $\widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^{{l}\times{m}}$ are the state and control weight matrices respectively, which are nonlinear in state.

We know that matrices $A(\mathbf{x}(t))$ and $B(\mathbf{x}(t))$ are partial derivatives of $\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)$ with respect to the state $\mathbf{x}(t) \in\mathbb{R}^{l}$ and control $\mathbf{u}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ variables respectively, therefore
\begin{align}
% 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)) } {\partial \mathbf{x}(t) } 
&=
\frac{\partial \bigg(\widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t))\mathbf{x}(t) + \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t))\mathbf{u}(t)\bigg) } {\partial \mathbf{x}(t) } \\
&= \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t)) + \frac{\partial \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } { \partial\mathbf{x}(t) }\mathbf{x}(t) + \frac{\partial \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } { \partial \mathbf{x}(t) }\mathbf{u}(t)\\
% 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)) } {\partial \mathbf{u}(t) } 
&=
\frac{\partial \bigg(\widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t))\mathbf{x}(t) + \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t))\mathbf{u}(t)\bigg) } {\partial \mathbf{u}(t) } = \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t))
\end{align}
where $\frac{\partial \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } {\partial \mathbf{x}(t) } \in \mathbb{R}^{{l}\times{l}\times{l}}$ and $\frac{\partial \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } { \partial \mathbf{x}(t) } \in \mathbb{R}^{{l}\times{m}\times{l}}$ are $3$-dimensional tensors, while $\frac{\partial \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } {\partial \mathbf{x}(t) }\mathbf{x}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{{l}\times{l }}$ and $\frac{\partial \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } { \partial \mathbf{x}(t) }\mathbf{u}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{{l}\times{m}}$ are $2$-dimensional matrices.

The nonlinear dynamics (see Eq of $\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)$) can be linearised around a point ($\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)},\mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)}$), $i=1,...,I$ using first order Taylor approximation
\begin{align}
% 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)
&=
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)},\mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)})
+ 
\Bigg(
 \left.\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t))}{\partial \mathbf{u}(t)}
 \right|_{\substack{\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}\\\mathbf{u}(t)=\mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)}}}
 \Big( 
  \mathbf{u}(t) - \mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)} 
 \Big)
\Bigg) 
+ 
\Bigg(
 \left.\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t))}{\partial \mathbf{x}(t)}
 \right|_{\substack{\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}\\\mathbf{u}(t)=\mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)}}} 
 \Big( 
  \mathbf{x}(t) - \mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)} 
 \Big) 
\Bigg)
\nonumber \\
% 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
&=
\Bigg(
 \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)})\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)} 
+ 
\widetilde{B}(\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)})\mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)} 
\Bigg)
+ 
\Bigg(
 \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}) 
 \Big( 
  \mathbf{u}(t) - \mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)} 
 \Big)
\Bigg)
\nonumber \\
% 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
& + 
\Bigg(
  \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}) 
  + 
  \frac{\partial\widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t))}{\partial \mathbf{x}(t)}\bigg|_{x(t)=\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}} \mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}
  +
  \frac{\partial\widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t))}{\partial \mathbf{x}(t)}\bigg|_{x(t)=\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}} \mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)}
\Bigg)
\bigg( 
 \mathbf{x}(t) - \mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)} 
\bigg) 
\end{align}

### Now come my actual questions:

1. I am highly concerned that this is incorrect: $\frac{\partial \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } { \partial \mathbf{x}(t) }\mathbf{u}(t)$, because $\frac{\partial \widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t)) } { \partial \mathbf{x}(t) }$ is $\in \mathbb{R^{l \times m \times l}}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ is $\in \mathbb{R^{m \times 1}}$. Therefore I don't think I can multiply the derivative by the $\mathbf{u}$ but how do I write this differentiation using the product rule then?
2. When I open up the brackets what is the answer? $\Bigg(
     \widetilde{A}(\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}) 
     + 
     \frac{\partial\widetilde{A}(\mathbf{x}(t))}{\partial \mathbf{x}(t)}\bigg|_{x(t)=\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}} \mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}
     +
     \frac{\partial\widetilde{B}(\mathbf{x}(t))}{\partial \mathbf{x}(t)}\bigg|_{x(t)=\mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)}} \mathbf{a}_{u}^{(i)}
   \Bigg)
   \bigg( 
    \mathbf{x}(t) - \mathbf{a}_{x}^{(i)} 
   \bigg) $

Comment: It is rather close to impossible to understand what you mean. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I edited the question to include everything as Latex. I just have not dealt with multiplying these things out before and not sure of how to write it correctly. Which options are correct please, if any :-)?

Comment: You want \partial, not \partderiv.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ takes one vector to give a linear application on $\mathbb{R}^\ell$, then you can write in coordinates $x=x^{j}$, $y=y^{k}$ and $A=A^{i}_{jk}$ where $i,j,k\in\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ and then write $A^{i}_{jk}x^jy^k$. This is the abstract index notation : $A^{i}_{jk}x^jy^k$ is the $i$-th coordinates of the vector obtained by applying $A$ to both vectors $x$ and $y$.

If you want to keep your vectorial notation, then for the first term you can write $A\textbf{x}\textbf{y}$ or $\left(A\textbf{x}\right)\textbf{y}$ or also $\left(A\textbf{x}\right)\left(\textbf{y}\right)$ because $A\textbf{x}$ is a linear map on $\mathbb{R}^\ell$. Take care of the notation $\textbf{y}^T\textbf{z}$ which is the inner product of $\mathbb{R}^\ell$ of $\textbf{y}$ with $\textbf{z}$ (both vectors!).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please clarify, you mean to be careful of notation $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}$ I think. I indeed agree that this was not a good option. What did you think of the 'quadratic' form $\mathbf{y}^TA\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: I meant that $\textbf{y}^T A\textbf{x}$ has no sense because $\textbf{v}^T \textbf{w}$ is the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^\ell$ between two vectors $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$, and here $A\textbf{x}$ is not a vector but a linear map (or a tensor of type $(1,1)$).

Comment: I am not sure I understand. When we have a quadratic form $\mathbf{x}^TC\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{x}^T$ is $\in \mathbb{1 \times l}$ and $C \in \mathbb R ^{l \times l}$, we are allowed to say $\mathbf{x}^TC$ because the dimensions agree. This is where my thinking is coming from for this form, since the dimensions of $\mathbf{x}^TA$ agree, because $\mathbf{x}^T$ is $\in \mathbb{1 \times l}$ and $A$ is $\in \mathbb{ R} ^{l\times l \times l}$.

Comment: Please see my original Qn, for which I actually now added my actual derivations, where one particular part, i.e. opening the brackets, is confusing me.

Comment: Good point here Katya : $\textbf{y}^TA\textbf{x}$ has indeed a sense when you consider it as a matix composition. But $\textbf{y}^TA\textbf{x}$ is a linear form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ whereas $A$ applied to both vectors $\textbf{x}$, $\textbf{y}$ is a new vector! Actually, you see here that the identification $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the matrices in column is not really good (it can be confusing), and that's why I proposed the abstract index notation.

Comment: As for you new question, could you write it better (I can not read it correctly) ? Note \partial for $\partial$ symbol and take care of the spaces between symbols in a formula when you have some \. I will try to answer it after your correction.

Comment: Dear Nicolas, thank you for your help. I hope that everything now is more clear and I really look forward to discussing the 2 questions with you. I am also not clear what it means to say ' a linear form on $\mathbb {R^{3}}$ '? The issue with the abstract index notation is that I don't think it is practical for my equations, which I am deriving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23162/discussion-between-nicolas-and-katya).